Manga where the main character gets isekaied into a sci-fi world where warships show the power of the family
I am searching for manga where the main character gets isekaied into a sci-fi world where warships show the power of the family. He belongs to a noble family but his mother wants to take over the family and her maternal side is quite strong.
He also gets bullied in warship school and tries to take revenge when he grows stronger.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And were the warships spaceships or seafaring ships?

it was mostly black and white and warships were spaceships

scifi isekai is pretty rare. The only ones I know of are "Reborn as a Space Mercenary" and "I am the Villainous Lord of the Interstellar Nation", neither of which includes the maternal aspect. Could you explicitly rule them out, just in case you're misremembering details or getting series mixed up?

I think it's Reborn as a Space Aristocrat or Tensei Shitara Uchu Kizoku.
It's the one where he becomes a great strategist on the front lines with the force granted to him due to his nobility, then crushes it when a force with a special type of ship comes in and he leaves in power armor. He returns home with the prestige of war and being commended for his victory, and the maternal family attempts to ambush him with a massive warship, only for him to catch both of their best-class warships in the noble grounds and city and outright destroy them.
I remember it, it's in my history watchlist, but I can't search it back for some reason. Maybe it's region-locked?

Its the one where he becomes a great strategist in the front lines with the force granted to him due to his nobility, then crushes it when a force with a special type of ship comes in and he leaves in power armor. He returns home with the prestige of war and being commended for his victory, and the maternal family attempts to ambush the with a massive warship, only for him to catch both of their best class warships in the noble grounds and city and outright destroy them.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/RebornAsASpaceMercenaryIWokeUpPilotingTheStrongestStarship?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?
